Multiple Monitors Won't go to Sleep When Locking Session - Ubuntu 24.04
Hardware:

CPU: Intel i5-14400
RAM: 32 GB
GPU (Integrated): Intel UHD 730
GPU (PEG): AMD Radeon RX 7600 TX
Monitors: 2 Lenovo L24 q-10 / 1 Dell P2422H

Software:

OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (fully updated including pro updates)
DE: GNOME 46
Display Server: Wayland

Problem:

I have 6 Workspaces setup.
All monitors are connected via HDMI: The 2 Lenovo's to the PEG GPU and the Dell to the Integrated GPU.
I have a terminal window open on a non-primary monitor, on the 3rd Workspace. Every time I unlock the session, the terminal window jups to the primary display on the same workspace.
When I lock the session (using Super+L), all monitors go to sleep (DPMS) and immediately wake up and stay on, sometimes with  black screen (but no stand-by).
I created a new user and tried locking the session - same effect.
I used to have an ancient nVidia GT730 worked just fine...

Any pointers welcome, including ways to troubleshoot. It's driving me nuts.
Thanks!
